# output for different changing variables

Tags: matlab, variables, numbers

I have 4 variables a,b,c,d. a can vary 1,2 i.e. a=1,2, b=1,2,3, c=1,2,3,4, d=1,2,3,4,5 so by varying each element I want to make output value i.e.

```
a b c d      output
1 1 1 1        1
1 1 1 2        2
1 1 1 3        3
1 1 1 4        4
1 1 1 5        5
```

now varying c with 1 value and d with all values i.e.

```
a b c d      output
1 1 2 1        6
1 1 2 2        7
1 1 2 3        8
1 1 2 4        9
1 1 2 5        10
```

now change c to 3 and doing above so getting output as 11,12,13,14,15. when c reaches max varying limit then change b i.e.

```
a b c d      output
1 2 1 1        16
1 2 1 2        17
1 2 1 3        18
1 2 1 4        19
1 2 1 5        20
```

then

```
a b c d      output
1 2 2 1        21
1 2 2 2        22
1 2 2 3        23
1 2 2 4        24
1 2 2 5        25
```

so like this I want to proceed and want output for all conditions of a,b,c,d. so how to do it or any equation to do this in matlab. in above a,b,c,d vary 2,3,4,5 i.e in increasing order but in general case they can vary without increasing order e.g. a,b,c,d can vary 7,4,9,13.

Comment: so for the given `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`, will your output matrix be `[1,2,3,....., 118,119,120]` ? (btw you skipped `c=4` without mentioning it in your question)

Comment: Are the ranges for the variables always `1:k` (for some positive k)? Do you care if the index is not in the order you specified, but some other sequential mapping?

Comment: If you got the answer you're looking for, you should accept it. If you didn't, you should clarify what you want.

Comment: I got answer which is different than mentions here, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A possible algorithm could be to buil the combinations column by column considering the number of times eache value has to be repeted starting form the array `d`

Defined:

- `len_a` the length of the array`a`
- `len_b` the length of the array`b`
- `len_c` the length of the array`c`
- `len_d` the length of the array`d`

you need to replicate the `d` array `len_a * len_b * len_c` times.

The array `c` needs to be replicated `len_c * len_d` times to cover the "right side" combination, the this set of data have to be replicated `len_a * len_b` times to account for the "left side" to come.

Similar approach applies for the definiton of the array `a` and `b`.

To have the set of combinations in a "random" sequence, is sufficient to
use the `randperm` function.

```
% Define the input arrays
a=1:2;
len_a=length(a);
b=1:3;
len_b=length(b);
c=1:4;
len_c=length(c);
d=1:5;
len_d=length(d);
% Generate the fourth column of the table
% 
d1=repmat(d',len_a*len_b*len_c,1)
% 
% Generate the third column of the table
c1=repmat(reshape(bsxfun(@plus,zeros(len_d,1),[1:len_c]),len_c*len_d,1),len_a*len_b,1)
% 
% Generate the second column of the table
b1=repmat(reshape(bsxfun(@plus,zeros(len_c*len_d,1),[1:len_b]),len_b*len_c*len_d,1),len_a,1)
% 
% Generate the first column of the table
a1=reshape(bsxfun(@plus,zeros(len_b*len_c*len_d,1),[1:len_a]),len_a*len_b*len_c*len_d,1)
% 
% Merge the colums and add the counter in the fifth column
combination_set_1=[a1 b1 c1 d1 (1:len_a*len_b*len_c*len_d)']
% Randomize the rows
combination_set_2=combination_set_1(randperm(len_a*len_b*len_c*len_d),:)
```

Output:

```
  1   1   1   1         1 
  1   1   1   2         2 
  1   1   1   3         3 
  1   1   1   4         4 
  1   1   1   5         5 

  1   1   2   1         6 
  1   1   2   2         7 
  1   1   2   3         8 
  1   1   2   4         9 
  1   1   2   5        10 

  1   1   3   1        11 
  1   1   3   2        12 
  1   1   3   3        13 
  1   1   3   4        14 
  1   1   3   5        15 

  1   1   4   1        16 
  1   1   4   2        17 
  1   1   4   3        18 
  1   1   4   4        19 
  1   1   4   5        20 

  1   2   1   1        21 
  1   2   1   2        22 
  1   2   1   3        23 
  1   2   1   4        24 
  1   2   1   5        25 

  1   2   2   1        26 
  1   2   2   2        27 
  1   2   2   3        28 
  1   2   2   4        29 
  1   2   2   5        30 

  1   2   3   1        31 
  1   2   3   2        32 
  1   2   3   3        33 
  1   2   3   4        34 
  1   2   3   5        35 

  1   2   4   1        36 
  1   2   4   2        37 
  1   2   4   3        38 
  1   2   4   4        39 
  1   2   4   5        40 

  1   3   1   1        41 
  1   3   1   2        42 
  1   3   1   3        43 
  1   3   1   4        44 
  1   3   1   5        45 

  1   3   2   1        46 
  1   3   2   2        47 
  1   3   2   3        48 
  1   3   2   4        49 
  1   3   2   5        50 

  1   3   3   1        51 
  1   3   3   2        52 
  1   3   3   3        53 
  1   3   3   4        54 
  1   3   3   5        55 

  1   3   4   1        56 
  1   3   4   2        57 
  1   3   4   3        58 
  1   3   4   4        59 
  1   3   4   5        60 

  2   1   1   1        61 
  2   1   1   2        62 
  2   1   1   3        63 
  2   1   1   4        64 
  2   1   1   5        65 

  2   1   2   1        66 
  2   1   2   2        67 
  2   1   2   3        68 
  2   1   2   4        69 
  2   1   2   5        70 

  2   1   3   1        71 
  2   1   3   2        72 
  2   1   3   3        73 
  2   1   3   4        74 
  2   1   3   5        75 

  2   1   4   1        76 
  2   1   4   2        77 
  2   1   4   3        78 
  2   1   4   4        79 
  2   1   4   5        80 

  2   2   1   1        81 
  2   2   1   2        82 
  2   2   1   3        83 
  2   2   1   4        84 
  2   2   1   5        85 

  2   2   2   1        86 
  2   2   2   2        87 
  2   2   2   3        88 
  2   2   2   4        89 
  2   2   2   5        90 

  2   2   3   1        91 
  2   2   3   2        92 
  2   2   3   3        93 
  2   2   3   4        94 
  2   2   3   5        95 

  2   2   4   1        96 
  2   2   4   2        97 
  2   2   4   3        98 
  2   2   4   4        99 
  2   2   4   5       100 

  2   3   1   1       101 
  2   3   1   2       102 
  2   3   1   3       103 
  2   3   1   4       104 
  2   3   1   5       105 

  2   3   2   1       106 
  2   3   2   2       107 
  2   3   2   3       108 
  2   3   2   4       109 
  2   3   2   5       110 

  2   3   3   1       111 
  2   3   3   2       112 
  2   3   3   3       113 
  2   3   3   4       114 
  2   3   3   5       115 

  2   3   4   1       116 
  2   3   4   2       117 
  2   3   4   3       118 
  2   3   4   4       119 
  2   3   4   5       120
```

Hope this helps.

Qapla'